# JPA Can't add a user entity to a project entity that to persist

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans, jax-rs

I'm having trouble with adding a user to the user collections of a project entity which I am to persist. In my database, a project has many users and a user can have many projects.

```
@POST
    @Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public void create(Project entity) {
        User user =  em.find(User.class, 1);
        Collection<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        users.add(user);
        entity.setUserCollection(users); //This does not works
        entity.setCreatedDate(new Date());
        entity.setStatus(1);
        getEntityManager().persist(entity); //super.create(entity);
    }
```

How can I do this?

My Project entity has this mapping

```
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projectCollection")
    private Collection<User> userCollection;
```

While my User entity has these

```
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_project", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "User_idUser", referencedColumnName = "idUser")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "Project_idProject", referencedColumnName = "idProject")})
    @ManyToMany
    private Collection<Project> projectCollection;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userCollection")
    private Collection<Project> ProjectCollection;
```

My DB structure is like [image: My DB structure]

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: It does not go to the database, I have a table as `user_has_project` user id and the project id should go to it

Comment: What you posted is not sufficient to diagnose the problem. We don't know how your entities are mapped, nor what `super.create(entity)` does.

Comment: added more details :)

Comment: That still doesn't tell me how the entities are defined and mapped, and what super.create() does. Post the code: that's where the problem is. Pictures rarely have bugs.

Comment: sorry, added the parts I think that is needed. O:) Or may I post the full class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mapping doesn't make any sense.

First:

```
private Collection<Project> projectCollection;
private Collection<Project> ProjectCollection;
```

Why do you have two different associations from User to Project, each named almost the same way? If you really have two different associations (like a user owning projects, and a user participating in projects), then choose meaningful names for these two associations, respecting the Java naming conventions, like

```
private Collection<Project> ownedProjects;
private Collection<Project> involvedProjects;
```

Second, look at the mapping:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projectCollection")
private Collection<User> userCollection;
```

This means: "I'm only the inverse side. To know how this bidirectional association is mapped, go look at User.projectCollection".

As documented, what JPA cares about in a bidirectional association is the owner side. The owner side is the side that does NOT have the `mappedBy` attribute. So, in order to persist an association between Project and User, what must be populated is `User.projectCollection`.

So your code should be:

```
    User user =  em.find(User.class, 1);
    Collection<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
    users.add(user);
    entity.setUserCollection(users); // useful to maintain coherence, but ignored by JPA
    entity.setCreatedDate(new Date());
    entity.setStatus(1);
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);

    user.getProjectCollection().add(entity); // necessary to have the association persisted
```

Comment: your answer is very informative. :) I can't figure out why there are two different associations from User to Project :/ May be bad re-factoring. Could it be the reason? I'm in a doubt which one I should remove. I'm a newbie.  
I tried the above code and now it seems it is correctly connecting, when I query projects of the user, it shows the newly added project. But it does not goes to the db. It seems it stays only in ram.

Comment: removed the unnecessary association also, and now it is working! :D Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Ad far as I know you cannot have mapped by on two sides of a ManyToMany. Also the Managing side of the relationship needs to maintain the relationship. Thus add and remove parts of the collection.

Try changing this in the User object.

```
 @JoinTable(name = "user_has_project", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "User_idUser", referencedColumnName = "idUser")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "Project_idProject", referencedColumnName = "idProject")})
@ManyToMany
private Collection<Project> projectCollection;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userCollection")
private Collection<Project> ProjectCollection;
```

Too

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userCollection")
private Collection<Project> projectCollection;
```

And the Project Entity too

```
@JoinTable(name = "user_has_project", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "Project_idProject", referencedColumnName = "idProject")
    }, inverseJoinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "User_idUser", referencedColumnName = "idUser")    
})
@ManyToMany
private Collection<User> userCollection;
```

See http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/ for full example